# What's the best way to format a SyntaxTree in memory?

Tags: c#, roslyn

The existing Roslyn documentation is very thin so I'm hoping someone knows how to do this, or at least point me in the right direction.  I tried a number of things, including the following to format the sourceCode but it didn't work:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(soureCode);
var root = (CSharpSyntaxNode)tree.GetRoot();
return root.ToFullString();
```

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Are you trying to format the whitespace? Do you have access to a `Document` or is it just a tree by itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're just trying to get a pretty-print version of your `SyntaxTree`, you can call `root.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();`.

[`NormalizeWhitespace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxextensions.normalizewhitespace?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.2.0) is an extension method, so you'll have to add:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
```

If you're looking to format the tree in memory, you're probably looking for the [`Formatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.formatting.formatter?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.2.0) class. This class has a few different overloads depending on whether you want to format the entire document or just certain spans.

Unfortunately, it requires either a `Document` or a `Workspace` to format the whitespace. It might be nice if there was an overload that just applied generic formatting rules to a tree.